# How to install Jaxon 2.0 in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Good day.

I followed the tutorial instruccions to install.

Installation

Add the following lines in the composer.json file, and run the composer update command.

```
"require": {
    "jaxon-php/jaxon-laravel": "~2.0"
}
```

But i recieve the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package jaxon-php/jaxon-laravel ~2.0 is satisfiable by jaxon-php/jaxon-laravel[v2.0-beta.1, v2.0-beta.2, v2.0-beta.3, v2.0-beta.4, v2.0-beta.5, v2.0-beta.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^6.20",
        "elibyy/tcpdf-laravel": "5.3.*",
        "iatstuti/laravel-nullable-fields": "~1.0",
        "orangehill/iseed": "2.2",
        "jaxon-php/jaxon-laravel": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Googling arround i think i found my problem:

Since jaxon is in BETA version and composer default minimun stability requeriments are STABLE, composer failed to install the package.

I added this 2 lines to my composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "beta",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

Source: 
http://webtips.krajee.com/setting-composer-minimum-stability-application/
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability